# Can we insert a row in a table with default values in each column using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am not sure if my question will find any solution and after searching I could not find a workaround.

**SCENARIO:**
I am developing a batch solution using SSIS. Which reads a query in data flow task. The query produces some row as result and I simply need to insert that result into destination table (in MS SQL Server database).

**CHALLENGE**

The challenge I see here is even if the SQL query does not produce any row, the destination table should be filled with default row. But with CTE produced in below query and in SSIS it doesn't seem to be that easy.

**SQL Query** plugged in SSIS OLE DB SOURCE EDITOR.

```
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = GETDATE();

with cte as
(
select
   T.mot_fleettypedescription AS 'FleetType'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize = 0 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_0'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize = 1 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_1'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_2-4'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_5-10'
   ,CONVERT(DATE, C.mot_monthenddate) AS 'MED'
from Filteredmot_carrierfleettypes F
left outer join Filteredmot_carrierfleettype T on F.mot_fleettype = T.mot_carrierfleettypeid
left outer join Filteredmot_fleetcount C on F.mot_carriernumber = C.mot_carriernumber
where F.statecode = 0 AND C.mot_monthenddate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@date)), @date))
group by F.mot_averagefleetsize, T.mot_fleettypedescription, C.mot_monthenddate
)

select 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), 'by Weight') AS 'Caption', cte.MED AS 'Date', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cte.FleetType) AS 'FleetType',
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), 'ALL') AS 'OperatingStatus',
    SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_0) As 'Fleet_Range_0', SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_1) As 'Fleet_Range_1', SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_2-4]) 'Fleet_Range_2-4', 
    SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_5-10]) 'Fleet_Range_5-10', 
    (SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_0) + SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_1) + SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_2-4]) + SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_5-10])) 'TOTAL'
from cte
where cte.FleetType = 'Bus'
group by cte.FleetType, cte.MED
```

**RESEARCH**
*If it was pure SQL server environment, I would have checked for number of rows returned using `COUNT(*)` or `@@ROWCOUNT` with below query segment. But I am not sure how to blend this part with above actual query in SSIS.*

```
DECLARE @CntOfRow INT;
select @CntOfRow = @@ROWCOUNT
--select @CntOfRow as 'Numrow'
if(@CntOfRow = 0)
begin
    if object_id ('tempdb..#Bus') is not null
    begin
        drop table #Bus
    end
    if object_id ('tempdb..#Bus') is null
    begin
        create table #Bus(
            Caption varchar(20), [Date] date, FleetType varchar(10), OperatingStatus varchar(25),
            Fleet_Range_0 int null, Fleet_Range_1 int null, [Fleet_Range_2-4] int null, [Fleet_Range_5-10] int null, TOTAL int null
        )
        insert into #Bus(Caption,[Date],FleetType,OperatingStatus, Fleet_Range_0,Fleet_Range_1,[Fleet_Range_2-4],[Fleet_Range_5-10],TOTAL)
        values('by Weight', CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@date)), @date)), 'Bus', 'ALL',0,0,0,0,0)
    end
    select * from #Bus
end
```

**INVESTIGATION**

I looked into SSIS components like `Row Count` and `Conditional Split` in a way to first get the count of row following source query and then apply conditional split to further insert the retrieved result in destination table. But after conditional split I am not sure how to generate a temporary table and insert a row with default values to further insert it to destination table.

I am also exploring the `Execute SQL Task` in control flow to see if I can shift logic to generate default row there and pass that row in DFT to insert into destination table.

Any insight to this scenario is very much appreciated.

**SNAPSHOT OF RESOLUTION**

[image: package with execute sql task]

Comment: One way is to use a Stored Procedure and do the logic and query in there.  DDL and DML are applicable in a Stored Procedure.  The SP will have to select something at the end, is the only condition I can think of.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do you mean I should think of including everything above in SP upto inserting record in destination table? NOTE: Source and destination are on two separate database. And with restrictions I can think of, I cannot use linked server.

Comment: Well, it sounds like that's not an option if the servers are not linked.  I don't think conditional split is the correct way... that is in a Data Flow level IIRC. You need to be in Control Flow level- create an SSIS integer variable; use a Row Count control or SQL query to count whatever you are attempting to count; save the result to the SSIS variable. Connect this row count control to two different data source controls for the 2 situations you describe... determine the control flow direction using the SSIS variable value (double-click the arrows leading to the data sources & program it).

Comment: @Binoy have you tried the suggestion below?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a complex SQL command in the OLEDB Source, try inserting data into a temp table, then check if the temp table doesn't contains rows insert default values. At the end select all rows from the temp table.

```sql
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @date = GETDATE();

with cte as
(
select
   T.mot_fleettypedescription AS 'FleetType'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize = 0 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_0'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize = 1 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_1'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_2-4'
   ,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN COUNT(C.mot_nscweight) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_5-10'
   ,CONVERT(DATE, C.mot_monthenddate) AS 'MED'
from Filteredmot_carrierfleettypes F
left outer join Filteredmot_carrierfleettype T on F.mot_fleettype = T.mot_carrierfleettypeid
left outer join Filteredmot_fleetcount C on F.mot_carriernumber = C.mot_carriernumber
where F.statecode = 0 AND C.mot_monthenddate = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@date)), @date))
group by F.mot_averagefleetsize, T.mot_fleettypedescription, C.mot_monthenddate
)
insert into #Bus(Caption,[Date],FleetType,OperatingStatus, Fleet_Range_0,Fleet_Range_1,[Fleet_Range_2-4],[Fleet_Range_5-10],TOTAL)
select 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50), 'by Weight') AS 'Caption', cte.MED AS 'Date', CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), cte.FleetType) AS 'FleetType',
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), 'ALL') AS 'OperatingStatus',
    SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_0) As 'Fleet_Range_0', SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_1) As 'Fleet_Range_1', SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_2-4]) 'Fleet_Range_2-4', 
    SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_5-10]) 'Fleet_Range_5-10', 
    (SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_0) + SUM(cte.Fleet_Range_1) + SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_2-4]) + SUM(cte.[Fleet_Range_5-10])) 'TOTAL'
from cte
where cte.FleetType = 'Bus'
group by cte.FleetType, cte.MED

DECLARE @Count INT
SELECT @Count = Count(*) FROM #Bus

If @Count = 0 
insert into #Bus(Caption,[Date],FleetType,OperatingStatus, Fleet_Range_0,Fleet_Range_1,[Fleet_Range_2-4],[Fleet_Range_5-10],TOTAL)
values('by Weight', CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@date)), @date)), 'Bus', 'ALL',0,0,0,0,0)

SELECT * FROM #Bus
```

If it doesn't works, try implementing this within a stored procedure

Comment: should I worry about temporary object? I.e. #Bus in this case.

Comment: @Binoy no you don't need to worry about #Bus here. It will only exist in the scope of the Data Flow. Once the Data Flow execution finishes, the temp table will be released. Even if you execute the Data Flow multiple times in a package (in a For Loop, for example), each time the Data Flow runs, a new #Bus is created and released.

Comment: @Hadi, with OLE DB source editor, given code does not work because somehow it does not recognize temporary object. I tested this code in SQL editor and worked with one addition that I have to first create temporary object '#Bus' before insert query. With organizational restriction, I can't create SP else my work was easy. Hence, with this limitations what I did is I added a "Execute SQL Task" at end of my container execution where in I check if record with particular caption id was inserted. If not than "Execute SQL Task" inserts default row.

Comment: @Binoy then you have to write your own answer